# JQuery Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

It's simple slide up animation. The problem is when I change "top" parameter of myDiv class, animation is working incorrectly, instead of sliding up, it slides down from top. It only works incorrectly when I click button for the first time. When I change myDiv's top parameter to a bigger number there is no more problem. Can you please help me to find what is wrong with the code.

```
   <style>
    .box {
        position:relative;
        width: 200px;
        height: 500px;
    }
    .myDiv {
        position: absolute;
        width:100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        bottom:0px;
        top:10px;
        left:500;
    }
</style>
<script>
    var swt = 0;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".b1").click(function () {

            var div = $(".myDiv");
            if (swt == 0) {
                div.animate({
                    top: '300px',
                    opacity: '1'
                }, "slow");
                //  div.animate({height:'300px', opacity:'1'},"slow");
                swt++;
            } else {
                div.animate({
                    top: '500px',
                    opacity: '1'
                }, "slow");
                //  div.animate({height:'0px', opacity:'1'},"slow");
                swt--;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="b1">Start Animation</button>
    <p>posds</p>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="myDiv" style="background:#7549B1; width:200px;"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have some typo in css. Why You enter both top and bottom position to .myDiv, and also whe lyeft has no px?

Comment: without top position in myDiv it's the same effect, first it goes down from top(only first time). And then it works normaly.

Comment: Because Your initial top poision (in css) is diffrent than one in js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure whay effect do you want, but maybe it's changing the `bottom` value instead of `top`:

```
if(swt==0){
    div.animate({bottom:'500px', opacity:'1'}, "slow");
    swt++;  
} else {
    div.animate({bottom:'300px', opacity:'1'}, "slow");
    swt--;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/ixigaf/1/edit

Comment: I wanted my div to appear from a certain position, sliding up. I've checked your sample, it works the same way only it slides down. If you would change top position of myDiv to 500px it will work the way I need, except first time you click the button it won't do anything. I will work on it more.

Comment: Look what Marcin Bobowsky commented above. If I understand correctly, the problem is on your initial div css, not the js. See http://jsbin.com/ixigaf/27/edit

Comment: I'm an idiot, not slide up, it's slide down. Anyway I will try to fix it based on your answer and Marcin's comment. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks man, I will just do it that way. :) http://jsbin.com/ixigaf/46/edit Now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `bottom` and `top` on a same element, it will create a conflict. Define height and animte top with negative value:

[**Here is jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/thGFN/11/)

```
if(swt==0){
       div.animate({top:'-300px', opacity:'1'}, "slow");
        swt++;  
}else{
      div.animate({top:'-500px', opacity:'1'}, "slow");
        swt--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Cyberek/yLBeK/

This is as I understand buggy, but if You change in css top from 10px to 100px (same as top in js) everything should be ok.

```
.myDiv {
        position: absolute;
        width:100px;
        height: 100px;
        overflow: hidden;
        top:100px;
        left:100px;
        background: red;
}

$(".b1").click(function () {

            var div = $(".myDiv");
            if (swt == 0) {
                div.animate({
                    top: '100px',
                    opacity: '1'
                }, "slow");
                //  div.animate({height:'300px', opacity:'1'},"slow");
                swt++;
            } else {
                div.animate({
                    top: '200px',
                    opacity: '1'
                }, "slow");
                //  div.animate({height:'0px', opacity:'1'},"slow");
                swt--;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I need to sleep now, thanks for help. I will fix it tomorrow. I'm such a noob.